# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_NUMBER_INT token

Tags: java, json, objectmapper

I am trying to load a `String` value into `List` of `Integers` , here is the sample code

```
import java.util.List;

public class Test2 {
private List<Integer> list;

public List<Integer> getList() {
    return list;
}

public void setList(List<Integer> list) {
    this.list = list;
  }
}

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String s = "1 2 3";
    //colorFrameAlertConfig.setColorNumber(objectMapper.readValue(configEntry.getValue(), List.class));
    Test2 t = new Test2();
    t.setList(objectMapper.readValue(s, List.class)); //getting exception here
    for(int i : t.getList()){
        System.out.println(i);
        }
  }

}
```

When I run the above code, I am getting following `exception`

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_NUMBER_INT token
at [Source: 1 2 3; line: 1, column: 1]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:270)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportMappingException(DeserializationContext.java:1234)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1122)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1075)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.handleNonArray(CollectionDeserializer.java:338)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:269)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:259)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:26)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3798)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2842)
at com.sample.Test.main(Test.java:17)
```

Comment: The String which you are passing in the parameter should be in a JSON form

Comment: Use "[1, 2, 3]"

Answer (score -1):

[check out the tutorial for better understanding](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/)